# WCF - web.config: independent service references [for self-hosted and IIS-hosting]

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

**QUESTION:** How to modify the web.config to support included WCF-ServiceApplication Service References with different addresses. In self-hosted and in IIS mode there are different addresses. Howto do it, without changing the web.config in each WCF-ServiceApplication for each deployment process. Can I request/update dynamically the service references?

**BACKGROUND:** I would like to host in IIS for external communication and self-hosted for internal communication, in order to support different protocols internal. And of course due to security issues. I have ~7 WCF-ServiceApplications web.configs to modify.

**PROBLEM**
The WCF-ServiceApplication depends on additional WCF-ServiceApplications as Services References. Depending on the hosting method, the address changes.

Self-hosted

```
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:50108/ABService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IABService"
            contract="ABServiceReference.IABService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IAndonBoardService" />
```

IIS

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:20200/AB/ABervice.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IABService"
            contract="ABServiceReference.IABService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IABService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:
[Configuring WCF Services in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277.aspx) and [Creating ServiceHostFactory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx)